# Swift 3 optional string to int

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am using Vapor for Swift backend. Following is the code i am working with.

```
drop.post("postTodo") { request in

var jsonContent: JSON?
if let contentType = request.headers["Content-Type"], contentType.contains("application/json"), let jsonData = request.json {
    jsonContent = jsonData
    print("Got JSON: \(jsonContent)")
}


guard let id = jsonContent?.node.object?["id"]?.string
    else {
        return JSON(["message": "Please include mandatory parameters"])
}

let tempId = Int(id)!
```

I am getting "id" as optional string for eg: Optional("123") for *jsonContent?.node.object?["id"]?.string*

When I try to convert it to int using Int(id)! i get back **nil**
If i try to do let tempId = Int(id!) it gives error.

But when i do the same thing in playground i get proper int value.

```
let id: String?

id = "1234"

let myInt = Int(id!)
```

Why Optional string to Int is not working properly in my Vapor app ? 
Any idea.

Comment: First guess is that `id` is already an Int... try not converting to string in the first place?

Comment: replace `let tempId = Int(id)!` with `let tempId = Int(id)`.

Comment: So how do i get int from json node object ? because if i call jsonContent?.node.object?["id"]?.int it will give nil and if i call jsonContent?.node.object?["id"]? then it will give Node.Node object.

Comment: @shallowThought i tried that but i gives complication error.

Answer (score 1):

If "id" is an optional string, then you probably don't want to be force unwrapping it with the "!".

The safest approach would be something like:

```
if let id = id
{
    let myIdAsInt = Int(id)
}
```

The reason it "works" in the playground, is you are definitely assigning a non-nil value to the string (therefore you get away with the force unwrap).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**String!**
might contain a string, or it might contain nil. It’s like a regular optional, but Swift lets you access the value directly without the unwrapping safety. If you try to do it, it means you know there’s a value there – **but if you’re wrong your app will crash**.

```
var optionalString: String? = "123"

// first check if it doesn't contain nil
if let str = optionalString {
    // string to -> Int
    if let id = Int(str) {
        print(id) // work with id
    }
} else {
    // optionalString contains nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

what i found is in my iOS code i had a `struct` with optional properties coz of  which when mapped to Dict gave object with optional values to keys.

If I make properties non optional and send it to vapor backend after it works fine.

So basically it was the case of using Optionals properly.